# How can I restore a MySQL database after formatting my hard drive

Tags: mysql, windows

I recently formatted my PC which had MySQL running on it.  As a result, I lost the databases on my hard drive.

I tried to restore the databases by re-installing the MySQL Server and putting the databases back into the MySQL datafiles folder.  When I started the MySQL service, I got error 1067: `Windows could not start the MySQL Service on local computer`.

If I just install MySQL and do not put my databases into the datafiles folder, I don't get the error.

How can I successfully restore my databases?

I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2 enterprise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After putting the data files, remove ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1. Dont delete ibdata1 file. And then restart MySQL service.

Before deleting take the backup of ib_logfiles and then delete.

Just give a try in this way.